# Looking for collected data concerning ux and web applications

Tags: measuring, data-analysis

Currently I'm trying to find out how to measure the user experience concerning web applications. I've already collected metrics like response time, device type, connectivity, bounce rate/conversion rate, geographical location of user, etc. that can help me with the calculation.

Now I would like to find out if these metrics correlate with each other (e.g. if user uses handheld-device, is response time less important?). Furthermore, I want to know if it is somehow possible to calculate the user experience with the help of these metrics.

I thought it could be helpful if I start a questionnaire and ask some people if they like a specific website depending on the metrics I mentioned above. But beforehand I want to have a look at some already performed questionnaires in the internet, but what I've found so far are only empty questionnaire templates.

My question: Does anybody of you know some completed questionnaires concerning the user experience of applications? Any data source that helps me to get a better insight in ux would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered the System Usability Scale (SUS)? http://www.measuringusability.com/sus.php

Comment: I've already had a look at it. It is definitely a good way to collect data. What I need is already collected data from questionnaires, surveys, etc.

Comment: Others have looked for SUS data repositories, to little avail: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21798/where-can-i-find-existing-system-usability-scale-sus-results-to-compare-agains

Comment: Erics, that's a good starting point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questionnaires can be valuable but be careful on jumping to conclusions. If you ask your customers if they would mind waiting 2 seconds for a page to load, everyone would reply 'yes', but if you really measured it in the field your conclusions would probably not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these kinds of metrics are unfortunately subjective.  You could create a formula that would work for measuring the user experience but it may only work for you and wouldn't be as objective as you'd like it to be.

I personally use [Google's Pagespeed Insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) tool.  While the formula is based on their ideas of what may be a good speed and good user experience metrics.  They provide scores for both Desktop and Mobile. They seem to use the same metrics that you have.